# Liferay Delegate Servlet cannot access liferay utility beans

Tags: java, spring, servlets, liferay

I am trying to build a delegate servlet in Liferay that needs to know the list of connected users in Liferay (using com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil)

I had no problem getting a simple delegated servlet to work and say Hello when deployed in Liferay, but when I try to use UserLocalServiceUtil I get this exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalService' is defined
```

Reading docs it seems that a delegate server could access core portal utilities, but could I be wrong. Any help or advice will be appreciated.

This is the servlet

```
package mycompany.liferay;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.service.UserServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.model.User;
import java.util.List;

public class myDelegateServlet extends HttpServlet {

 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

       try {

            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>My delegate Servlet</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>My delegate Servlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");

            int userCount = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsersCount();
            List<User> users = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers(0, userCount);

            out.print("<br>Connected Users:<br>");
            for (User user : users) 
              {
               out.print("<li>User: "+user.getUserId()+"</li>" );   
              }

            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
            {
             out.print("Exception! "+e.getMessage() );   
             }          
        finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
...
```

and this its definition at web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myDelegateServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalDelegateServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>servlet-class</param-name>
        <param-value>mycompany.liferay.myDelegateServlet</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sub-context</param-name>
        <param-value>myDelegateServlet</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: what version of Liferay are you on?

Comment: Liferay Community Edition Portal 7.0.3 GA4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this sample servlet. https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/master/gradle/extensions/servlet. The approach that you mentioned is more for the 6.2 version.

Then when you have the OSGi component you can easily inject services.

```
@Reference
private UserLocalService servcie;
```

You need to have the dependency `org.osgi:org.osgi.service.component.annotations:1.3.0`

Alternatively have a look at the JAX-RS interface

Comment: Even I have not tried yet the OSGi solution, you have helped me a lot pointing to right Liferay version. The imports I had correspond to version 6.x.  In version 7 they are a bit different. Intead of " com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil"  the correct import is "com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.UserLocalServiceUtil" and so on.  Now it works.  I am trying the OSGi way as you suggested as it is quite interesting. Thanks a lot.